# Python filtering array using the any() function

Tags: python, arrays, any

I am trying to write a program that recommends books by taking two inputs:

- The maximum amount of money the customer is prepared to spend.
- A string that consists of the first letters of all desired attributes ("horror", "scifi", "romance", "fantasy").

The desired attribute input should be a string such as sh or shf (the order should not matter therefore the string "shf" is treated the same as "fhs").

I have successfully created a filter that filters out the books that exceed the customer's maximum cost. However, the function continues to output any books that are in **any** of the categories provided by the user, not books that meet **all of the categories** as required (e.g. books that are both in fantasy and romance, for example). I've tried to replace the `any()` function with the `all()` function, but this does not seem to rectify the issue. Can anyone provide suggestions as to where I am going wrong?

```py
def recommend_books(max_price, cats):
    if not set(cats).issubset(set(book_categories)):
        raise ValueError(f'{cats} contains an invalid category code')
    cats_f = [cat for cat_i, cat in book_categories.items() if cat_i in set(cats)]
    return [book for book, price, cats in book_data
            if (price <= max_price and all(True for cat in cats if cat in cats_f))]


book_data = [["Harry Potter", 8, ["fantasy", "romance"]],
             ["IT", 11, ["horror", "fantasy"]],
             ["Star Wars", 22, ["scifi", "romance", "fantasy"]],
             ["Carrie", 13, ["horror"]],
             ["Lord of the Rings", 29, ["fantasy", "romance"]]
             ]

book = [book[0] for book in book_data]

book_categories = {}
for book, price, category in book_data:
    for cat in category:
        cat_initial = cat[0]
        if not cat_initial in book_categories:
            book_categories[cat_initial] = cat

recommend_books(25, "hf")
# Output should be an array of the Titles of the suitable book recommendations
# I.e. ["IT"]
```

The output for this example is: ['Harry Potter', 'IT', 'Star Wars', 'Carrie'] which is an array of all horror and fantasy books less than 25, so the filter does not appear to be working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing my answer after your comment:

your second condition in the filtering should be :

```
all(elem in cats for elem in cats_f)
```

and the complete function:

```
def recommend_books(max_price, cats):
        if not set(cats).issubset(set(book_categories)):
            raise ValueError(f'{cats} contains an invalid category code')
        cats_f = [cat for cat_i, cat in book_categories.items() if cat_i in set(cats)]
        return [book for book, price, cats in book_data 
                if (price <= max_price and **all (True for cat in cats if cat in cats_f))**]
```

iterating over all the categories(`cat_f`) you want to have, and check if all of them are in the book's categories(`cats`)

this produces your desired output.

Comment: Sorry, it might have been the way I phrased it. print(recommend_books(25, "hf")) should return the books that are both horror AND fantasy whose cost is less than or equal to 25 so it should return: ['IT']. However, instead the function returns all horror and fantasy books less than 25, so the filter does not appear to be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
def recommend_books(max_price, cats):
    if not set(cats).issubset(set(book_categories)):
        raise ValueError(f'{cats} contains an invalid category code')
    cats_f = [cat for cat_i, cat in book_categories.items() if cat_i in set(cats)]
    return [book for book, price, cats in book_data
            if (price <= max_price and all (cat in cats for cat in cats_f))]
```